# How do I get the length of UTF-8 string PHP?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, string-length

My Problem is, that I want to get the length of a String with special chars (like ä,ü,ö etc.). This string is saved in a variable. 
I've tried to get the length with `mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8'));` but it's returned wrong.. 
But I think I've got a problem solving approach..

Because when I write the String that is in this variable into mb_strlen by myself like 
`mb_strlen('äöü', 'UTF-8'));` the correct length is returned. So maybe something is wrong with the encoding of the variable (the variable is filled by the input of a user)

Comment: What kind of length do you want? In bytes? Could be between 6 and 9. Unicode codepoints? Could be between 3 and 6. Graphemes? Would be 3. Anything else? That said, provide the code to reproduce the problem, using the `"\xab"` syntax for the strings, so the content is reproducible regardless of the sourcefile encoding.

Comment: Why do you want the length of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the input (`$string`) is in another encoding - probably iso-8859-1 (especially if `mb_strlen() == strlen()`).

If `$string` has come from a form input, you need ensure that the form in posting in UTF-8 format. Unless specified the default is often iso-8859-1.

This is done with decent browsers by doing:

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
```